# Display error on ajax response from php function

Tags: javascript, php

I have some ajax call like this

```
function ExportData() {
  var data = {
    action: "export_database", // the name of your PHP function!
  };

  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function () {},
    success: function (data) {
      alert(data);
    },
  });
}
```

And php function like this

```
function export_database(){
  return $response;
}
```

The problem is in that response I have something like this

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|3fa58ee1-48bf0cb9f60bfa25."
}
```

I want to alert only title, but when i try **data.title** , i got **undefine**
Do I must encode or decode something, thanks?

Comment: while returning from `export_database` function, return like `json_encode($response)`. and then you can use `JSON.parse(data)` in JS.

Comment: Maybe you need to parse JSON? Using JSON.parse(response).

Comment: see the updated answer. Let me know.

Comment: @MiomirDancevic did u try doing what I suggested?

Comment: @RohitAmbre i do not think there is a need on the php side to do `json_encode` as the response he is getting is already an `json` object.

Comment: I think he is getting string. @MiomirDancevic can you try `typeof data` in `success` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need. Just access the object by `data.title` and it will show in the `alert()`

You need to define `dataType` as json in your request.

If its does not work then use `JSON.parse(data)` like this:

```
var response = JSON.parse(data)
alert(response.title)
```

Try below:

```js
function ExportData() {
  var data = {
    action: "export_database", // the name of your PHP function!
  };

  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajaxurl,
    dataType: 'json'
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function () {},
    success: function (data) {
      alert(data.title);
    },
    error: function(error){
      //Error
      alert(error.title)
    }
  });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried alert(data.title); but i got undefined??

Answer (score 1):

Try Below:

```
    function ExportData() {
      var data = {
        action: "export_database", // the name of your PHP function!
      };

      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function () {},
        success: function (data) {
          var parsedData = jQuery.parseJSON(data)
          alert(parsedData.title);
        },
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JSON.parse() for accessing data objects Like this:

```
function ExportData() {
  var data = {
    action: "export_database", // the name of your PHP function!
  };

  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function () {},
    success: function (data) {
var res = JSON.parse(data)
      alert(res.title);
    },
  });
}
```